# Drawing Multiple Rectangles on a Canvas in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I'm trying to draw a row of rectangles across my Canvas. When I run the following code, I only get one rectangle, even though my canvas element says it has 12 children.
Dimensions is a class with 2 integer properties, Height and Width. The canvas I am drawing this is on 400px by 600px.

```
Dimensions windowDimensions = new Dimensions()
        {
            Width = (int)cvsGameWindow.Width,
            Height = (int)cvsGameWindow.Height
        };

        //init rectangles
        for (int i = 0; i < windowDimensions.Width; i+=50)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(); //create the rectangle
            rect.StrokeThickness = 1;  //border to 1 stroke thick
            rect.Stroke = _blackBrush; //border color to black
            rect.Width = 50;
            rect.Height = 50;
            rect.Name = "box" + i.ToString();
            Canvas.SetLeft(rect,i * 50);
            _rectangles.Add(rect);
        }
        foreach (var rect in _rectangles)
        {
            cvsGameWindow.Children.Add(rect);
        }
```

and the private members declared at the top of my code:

```
private SolidColorBrush _blackBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
private SolidColorBrush _redBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
private SolidColorBrush _greenBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
private SolidColorBrush _blueBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
private List<Rectangle> _rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the culprit:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(rect,i * 50);
```

On the first loop, with `i=0`, you're setting `Canvas.Left = 0`; Since your for loop is doing `i+=50`, on the second loop i will be `50`, so you'll be setting `Canvas.Left = 2500`. You said your `Canvas` is `400x600`, so your rectangles are off-screen.

The simplest fix: use `Canvas.SetLeft(rect, i)` - since `i` is increasing in increments of 50.

Comment: Thanks. And how I didn't catch that I have no idea XD